# Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, xcode

Xcode build done.                                           15.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): File not found:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Encountered error while building for device.

Clean Build not works.

Comment: Looks like your Xcode installation is damaged/corrupted, that file should be present. I suggest deleting and reinstalling Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode --> Runner ---> Supported Platforms option change = "iphoneos" change to "ios" and open the project.

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter run

if not working reinstall Xcode